# Html decoder utility not showing all html in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

While looping through a list of items in a model, I'm trying to pull some columns in my view that have html and when using this

```
<td> @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Desc)) </td>
```

inside a table column, any bullets or numbering that is contained in the item.Desc is not showing up on the view.

An example `item.Desc` would look like this below.

```
<ul>
    <li>We have a first section for the first bullet point.&nbsp;</li>
    <li>We have a second section for another bullet point</li>
</ul>
```

In the view, the text shows, and it is indented as it should be, but that's all it shows. While stepping through the view, it shows the  tags and the html viewer in VS 2012 shows the bullets and/or numbering correctly.  I'm trying to figure out why the bullets and numbering are missing.

Any help with identifying why the bullets and numbering aren't showing in my view would be great!

Comment: "View source" in browser likely will show you the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you are using CSS that hides the bullets/numbering for `ul` and `ol` objects? I would suggest inspecting the element with your favorite browser's debugging tools to see what styles are applied to it.

Comment: Cory you had the right idea--- found there was a li liststyle set to none which was causing the issue.

Comment: Cory you should throw your comment in an answer and so i can upvote---